Is the line "love love love I want your love" in Bad Romance borrowed?
When I listened to Bad Romance by Lady Gaga I cannot shake away the feeling that the line "love love love I want your love" (timestamp 0:56) is something I've heard somewhere else. It could be the lyrics, the melody or both.
Am I right or do I have a false memory? If I'm right, where does it come from?

This is quite subjective naturally and I can't really say that the particular riff isn't an original one. There's countless of songs containing the word "love" for sure.
First thing I can think of is an old funk song _CHIC - I Want Your Love which is kind of similar both lyrics wise and a somewhat similar bassline.
Looking at more famous and mainstream artists,
I believe she was also inspired by Queen a lot and not just by getting her artist name from them (though some some nonsense parts "Ra-ra-ra" of Bad Romance kind of remind of nonsense parts in Radio Gaga). Speculating:

In the Queen + David Bowie song Under pressure there's a line echoing "love love love" at 2:36 into the song.
Melody-wise there are in fact lots of Queen songs with prominent basslines, funk/disco ones like Body Language or perhaps Another One Bites The Dust.
Lyrics wise there's also the power ballad Somebody to Love.


I think it's just me who is confused. I feel so sure that I've heard the melody for that line somewhere else, exactly or VERY similar to the melody of that line in Bad Romance. Possibly with other lyrics. But it seems like it's a false memory.
